# Master Page Layout Not Visible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web, master-pages

I created a website using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and when I started creating it, it displayed correctly when debugging and when viewing in a browser. However, now for some reason, it doesn't show the correct layout. It only shows the text and controls. It doesn't show the colors or other layout content which includes formatting of the content. Has anyone else ran into this issue? FOr the record, I never modified the Site.master page. I have cleared the cache and restarted Visual Studio as well. The website displays correctly in the "Design View" but in a web browser it displays incorrectly. Any ideas on how I can fix this issue? Here is the code for the "Login.aspx" page that I'm having trouble with to start.

```
<%@ Page Title="Dodge Main" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="Account_Login" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
```

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Log In
</h2>
<p>
    Please enter your username and password.</p>
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <span class="failureNotification">
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </span>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
        <div class="accountInfo">
            <fieldset class="login">
                <legend>Account Information</legend>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <p class="submitButton">
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Comment: make sure its pointing to the correct CSS file and make sure the path is correct.

Comment: Ok I have verified that the Site.master file is pointing to the correct CSS file. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you post up some code of the page that you are trying to view that references the master page

Comment: @DFord I have updated the post with code.

Comment: In the Login.aspx, you don't close the <asp:Content> tag, or you did not post it. Other than that, nothing pops out at me yet.

Comment: @DFord Thats weird because when I went to edit the post, it shows it in there.

Comment: After doing some digging, it looks as though the formatting is incorrect when I try to access a page that has restrictions and redirects you to login. AFter I login, and then try to access pages that were formatted incorrectly, they now show up formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a security issue. When I removed all of the roles and security from the settings, the look changed back to normal. Weird.